# How to permanently add an event like (touchStart) to all elements in WebStorm/IntelliJ (with Angular)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In WebStorm with Angular, the "Undefined binding" inspection will flag undefined events on elements.  How do we permanently add specific exceptions to this?  For example, in the following, the `(touchstart)` event gets flagged:

```
<button class="keypad-button" (touchstart)="onKeypadKeyPress($event, '1')">1</button>
```

But we use this `(touchstart)` event handler **everywhere**, in hundreds of files and projects.  And we can't simply disable the inspection -- we want it to work normally everywhere else.

Is there a way to add this particular event to an exception list permanently, across all files across all projects?  Or can we update WebStorm's definition of a valid element's events?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow [WEB-44387](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44387) for updates; for now, I can only suggest suppressing the inspection by adding `<!--suppress AngularUndefinedBinding -->` to the top of your file